# Is it possible to bundle a 3rd party extension in your visual studio integrated shell application?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-shell

I have written a language and debug engine extension for visual studio, and I'm able to create a shell application from this extension. However, I'd like to include [p4vs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PerforceSoftware.P4VS-PerforcePluginforVisualStudio), as it's a pain trying to install that to the shell seperately, as the installer doesn't target shell applications.

Comment: it is a extension for visual studio, which does not support visual studio shell, I would suggest that you could contract the author of extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that this is indeed possible by following the instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332502.aspx).

But the basic gist is:

1. Create a subfolder in the Extensions/ subfolder
2. Rename the vsix extension to ".zip"
3. Using your favourite zip file manager, extract the files to your newly created extension folder from step 1
4. Delete the [Content_types].xml file
5. Optionally, edit the vsixmanifest file and add InstalledByMsi="true" to the  element to prevent users from uninstalling the extension via the extension manager